# Informix - where clause with merge into

Tags: sql, merge, informix

I am using `Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC9W1X2`.

I need to update a table with fields from a different table. I am attempting to use the

```
MERGE INTO
```

statement, but I am not able to use a `WHERE CLAUSE` to filter out information from the table that is being updated as it's causing a syntax error. I also tried adding `AND` to the `WHEN MATCHED` and it isn't working.

Is there any way to do this?

This is my statement so far,

```
MERGE INTO table1 as t1
USING table2 as t2
   ON t1.some_no = t2.some  
WHEN MATCHED   
    THEN 
UPDATE SET t1.some_other_no = t2.some_other_no, is_processed = 'Y', resolution = 'AAA'
```

Comment: So you are trying to filter rows that are being updated in "table1"....so you have rows where t1.some_no = t2.some and you don't want them updated?  Have you tried to add the additional filters to the "ON" clause...so something like ON t1.some_no = t2.some AND t1.other_charcolumn != "blah"

Comment: @jrenaut yes that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional filters on table1 can be placed in the ON clause.  For example:

```
create table t1(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

insert into t1 values(1,1,1);
insert into t1 values(1,2,0);
insert into t1 values(1,3,0);
insert into t1 values(2,1,0);
insert into t1 values(3,1,1);

create table t2 (col1 int, col2 int);

insert into t2 values(1,5);
insert into t2 values(2,5);
insert into t2 values(3,5);


merge into t1
using t2
on
    t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col3 = 1
when matched then
    update set t1.col2 = t2.col2;

The above results in the following output when selecting from the t1 table

       col1        col2        col3

          1           5           1
          1           2           0
          1           3           0
          2           1           0
          3           5           1
```